# ios swift struct in variable

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to learn how to use structs in a class. I have a view controller in which I want to be able to switch a collection view data provider from two different sources so I set up dataprovider struct as such:

```
struct DataProvider {
    var apiPath: String
    var items: Array<CollectionItem>
    var pagination: Pagination
}
```

then I am creating two providers in my class such:

```
let dataProvider1 = DataProvider(apiPath: "1", items: [], pagination: Pagination(currentPage: 1, totalPages: 1, itemsPerPage: 20))
let dataProvider2 = DataProvider(apiPath: "2", items: [], pagination: Pagination(currentPage: 1, totalPages: 1, itemsPerPage: 20) )
```

I want to be able to store the current provider in a variable:

```
var currentDataProvider: DataProvider?
```

Everytime I assign the variable it creates a new dataprovider though

```
switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        currentDataProvider = self.dataProvider1
    case 1:
        currentDataProvider = self.dataProvider2
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how `struct`s work in Swift. `struct` is passed **by value**, while `class` is passed **by reference**. If you need to access same instance of `DataProvider` then define it as `class`.